# Submit Form Via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html file with a form containing a submit button, and an anchor tag that is outside of the form.  Is it possible to "simulate" the submit button from the anchor link?

In other words can a JavaScript function "call" submit for a form on the page?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure you can use the [`submit()`](http://www.roseindia.net/javascript/javascript-submit-method.shtml) method to submit a form like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.FormName.submit()">Submit Form</a>
```

Or

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('formID').submit()">Submit Form</a>
```

To go unobstrusive, you can do this instead:

**HTML:**

You can give your link an id:

```
<a href="#" id="link">Submit Form</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var link = document.getElementById('link');

  link.onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById('formID').submit();
    return false;
  };
</script>
```

where `formID` is the `id` of the `form`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this might work... (Assuming that you give an id to your submit button.)

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('theSubmitButton').click();return false;">Submit form</a>
```