# How can I submit a form automatically (onevent) with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'd like to be able to submit a form automatically on an event ( a generic form, for user tracking).

For example, create a POST to 
    http://www.example.com/index.php?option=track&variable=variable
    application/x-www-form-urlencoded with stuff like

```
username=usernamestring
otherdata=otherdata_string
otherdata2=otherdata string 2
```

The actual string will be preformatted, though, because all it is is like a 'ping'. 
It needs to be submitted onevent, with external js ( http://example.com/scripts/js.js )

What the hay should I do? This is getting annoying.

Update: I guess I didn't really make myself clear; I have a premade form that isn't supposed to display on the page; it needs to submit on an event. The form fields do not exist on the page; all I do is link to the script on the page and it executes onLoad.

POST uri: http://www.example.com/index.php?option=track&variable=variable
The arguments above (option=track and variable=variable) are not the form details (postdata).

The content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded , and has the following keys/values.

```
username=usernamestring
otherdata=otherdata_string
otherdata2=otherdata string 2 (when encoded, the spaces get turned to %20's.)
```

I need a script that submits this when run.

Comment: Thanks, wish I'd been told that sooner. Although sometimes one doesn't always get an adequate answer, I usually turn out fine.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484517/submit-form-via-javascript

Comment: It's not solved..I don't have my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You have to get the form object and call the `submit();` function provided by `HTMLFormObject`.

```
document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

1) with the following, (while page is loaded), the form will be immediately autosubmited

```
<form action="post.php" name="FNAME" method="post">
<input type="text" name="example22" value="YOURVALUE" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/JavaScript">document.forms["FNAME"].submit();</SCRIPT>
```

another formSubmit alternative - submits any script:

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

2) or use button click after 2second:

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/JavaScript">setInterval(function () {document.getElementById("myButtonId").click();}, 2000);</SCRIPT>
```